GitLab and GitLab Runner Container Issue: Clone URL Contains Container ID Instead of Actual URL
I’ve set up two containers: one for GitLab and one for GitLab Runner using docker.
Everything works fine, but I’ve encountered an issue where the clone URL shown in the GitLab interface contains the GitLab container ID instead of the actual URL I'm using.
GitLab URL:
http://192.168.188.100:8082/devops/automation
Clone URL (shown in GitLab UI):
http://8a756b29159c/devops/automation.git
The problem is that the clone URL shows a hostname that corresponds to the container ID (8a756b29159c), making it inaccessible from my network. This mismatch is preventing me from cloning repositories correctly.
